# how to add "Return Product" after "Product Delivery" functionality in node.js

Tags: node.js, product

I have build a product delivery application, and un-able to implement "Return Product" after "Product Delivery" using node.js. Can someone please guide.

I set a variable associated to product_id, when it become true then the product delivery is successful and set a countdown of 7 days, within which if a user clicks on "Return Product" then it will become a return will be initiated. But it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular _[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ Also recommended are Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.